# Apply security group to ECS container instances dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

If I want all the ECS container instances to be accessible by SSH from our corporate network I need to apply a security group for each instance. Since ECS spins up instances when needed this can not be done manually beforehand.

How do I make sure that all ECS container instances dynamically get a specific security group assigned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question; it is pretty obvious in the end.

After creating a service, a security group is created following the step as shown in Çağatay's answer. This security group can simply be updated as any other security group, which solves the issue.

Leaving this here for anyone who couldn't find it either.

Answer (score 4):

If you created your cluster via AWS Console, there is a option to assign Security Group for any instance created for the cluster.

[image: AWS Console]

In case of you use Cloudformation, you can check the reference architecture [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html). This Cloudformation template defines a Security Group for container instances.

Comment: I use that rule for exposing the application port to an internal ELB. It would be nice if I could add another such rule.

Comment: You can add multiple rules to a single security group. If you want a more flexible configuration, I'd use Cloudformation which you can control almost everything and you'd have a source controlled infrastructure as code. You can move your configuration to different AWS accounts etc..

Comment: Doesn't ECS use Cloudformation under water? I don't see how I can access that directly?

Comment: It does not. You have to write a template and install it to Cloudformation to install an ECS stack. The link I pasted gives all the knfo.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does use Cloudformation if you set it up through the console. But your answer did lead me to the solution, albeit through the aws command-line tool only. I can update the Cloudformation stack definition there. Need to dig into the details a bit more first, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!